# PyTorch Python && C++ inconsistent results from shared model

Tags: python, c++, pytorch, torch, torchvision

I am running a Python3 trained, torch_script exported CNN with C++.
However, I can not reproduce results on testing data.

The class labels the classifier returns in respective language are opposite for the identical data patch. Not sure if some memory is corrupted in the C++ implementation, but I was able to validate at least the Python implementation gives correct results. How else shall I debug? Right now I am trying to compare the weight matrices of the conv kernels to validate the model is consistent among both implementations.

Check the last lines in the code to see the difference.

Note - patch stats are identical between both languages, could be that the memory is misaligned in C++?

Anything else I can check?

Python export script:

```
    cnn = CNN1()

    cnn.load_state_dict(torch.load(args.cnn))

    torch_script_nn = torch.jit.script(cnn)

    script_file_name = args.cnn.replace('.torch', '.pytorch_script')
    torch_script_nn.save(script_file_name)

    print('{} CONVERTED TO {} '.format(args.cnn, script_file_name))
```

Python test script

```
    cnn = CNN1()
    cnn.load_state_dict(torch.load(cnn_file))

    i = 100
    j = 100
    patch_size = 14
    img = np.load(f)['arr_0']
    # plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray');plt.show()

    patch = img[i: i+ patch_size, j:j+patch_size]
    print('Patch max : {}, min {}'.format(np.max(patch), np.min(patch)))

    plt.imshow(patch, cmap='gray');plt.show()
    patch = np.expand_dims(patch, axis=2)
    normalized_patch = (patch - np.min(patch)) / np.max(patch - np.min(patch))
    print('Normalized Patch max : {}, min {}'.format(np.max(normalized_patch), np.min(normalized_patch)))
    torch_stack = torch.stack([torch.Tensor(normalized_patch)])
    print(torch_stack.shape)
    res = cnn(torch_stack.permute(0, 3, 1, 2))

    print('Class label {}'.format(res))
```

Prints

```
Patch max : 16.035221099853516, min 11.432785987854004
Normalized Patch max : 1.0, min 0.0
torch.Size([1, 14, 14, 1])
tensor([[9.9995e-01, 5.4011e-05]], grad_fn=<SoftmaxBackward>)
```

C++ test

```
std::cout << "TESTING CNN" << std::endl;
    std::size_t i = 100;
    std::size_t j = 100;

    const cv::Rect roi(i, j, patchSize, patchSize);
    cv::Mat amplitudePatch = amplitude(roi);
    double min;
    double max;
    cv::minMaxLoc(amplitudePatch, &min, &max);
    std::cout << "Patch Max : " << max << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Patch Min " << min << std::endl;

    cv::imshow("Patch", amplitudePatch);
    cv::Mat normalizedPatch = normalizeAmplitudePatch(amplitudePatch);
    cv::imshow("NPatch", normalizedPatch);
    cv::minMaxLoc(normalizedPatch, &min, &max);
    std::cout << "Normalized Patch Max : " << max << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Normalized Patch Min " << min << std::endl;

    cv::waitKey(0); 
    auto options = torch::TensorOptions().dtype(torch::kF32);

    std::cout << 1 << " " << amplitudePatch.size().height<< " " <<
        amplitudePatch.size().width<< " " << amplitudePatch.channels() << std::endl;

    torch::Tensor patchTensor = torch::from_blob(
      amplitudePatch.data, 
      {1, amplitudePatch.size().height,
        amplitudePatch.size().width, amplitudePatch.channels()},
      options);

    std::vector<c10::IValue> inputs;
    inputs.push_back(patchTensor.permute({0, 3, 1, 2}));
    torch::Tensor result = cnn.forward(inputs).toTensor();

    std::cout << result << std::endl;
```

Prints

```
Patch Max : 16.0352
Patch Min : 11.4328
Could not initialize OpenGL for RasterGLSurface, reverting to RasterSurface.
Could not initialize OpenGL for RasterGLSurface, reverting to RasterSurface.
Normalized Patch Max : 1
Normalized Patch Min 0
1 14 14 1
 0  1
[ Variable[CPUFloatType]{1,2} ]
```

Comment: You didn't set models to `eval` mode either in `python` nor in `cpp`. Simply call `cnn.eval()` in `python`  and `cpp` and see whether anything changes (you could run python multiple times unseeded and check whether results vary, if so, it's probably due to that).